# The term 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.BacPackage::Load' is not recognized

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

I have created a bacpac from an azure sql db, copied it to blob, from blob brought it down locally.

I run this code in powershell

```
Add-Type -path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll"
$restoredDatabaseName = 'AuditTest'
$bacpacFile = "H:\backup\audit\audit.bacpac"
$conn = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=master;Connection Timeout=0;Integrated Security=True;"

$importBac = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices $conn
$loadBac = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.BacPackage::Load($bacpacFile)
$importBac.ImportBacpac($loadBac, $restoredDatabaseName)

#Clean up
$loadBac.Dispose()
```

Get this error back:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.BacPackage::Load : The term 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.BacPackage::Load' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I have also tried to use the import data tier wizard and get the following error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.DacWizard)
```

It is driving me nuts, I have found a few things about registry hacking and so on  for the wizard error, nothing helpful at all for the powershell one.

SQL Azure DB PRS1
Restoring to  SQL 2016 in an Azure VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When invoking a static method, the full type name goes in square brackets.

So should be:

```
Add-Type -path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll"
$restoredDatabaseName = 'AuditTest'
$bacpacFile = "H:\backup\audit\audit.bacpac"
$conn = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=master;Connection Timeout=0;Integrated Security=True;"

$importBac = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices $conn
$loadBac = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.BacPackage]::Load($bacpacFile)
$importBac.ImportBacpac($loadBac, $restoredDatabaseName)

#Clean up
$loadBac.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks very much, new to powershell and was just copying examples I found online. Giving it a try now, it doesn't appear to have failed yet.

Comment: IT WORKS. Amazing.